# How can I position elements absolutely on a page?

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry, picture-mode, everypage

I am trying to position elements absolutely on a page. These positioned elements use the `put{}` command itself. The coordinate origin should *always* be in the top left corner on every page, also when changing the page layout (by using `\newgeometry{}`).

---

To achieve this I want to use the second parameter set of the `picture` environment. This should translate my coordinate system to the top left corner of the paper.

The position of the `picture` environment is defined by the position of the header and/or the page layout. So the second set of parameters should depend on any or multiple of the page margins. When the page changes the margins will change and my origin will stay the same.

So in other words: I am trying to calculate back the position of the header/`picture`-environment. When I know how this position is calculated relative to the top left corner I can calculate back the position from inside the header to the top left paper corner.

For setting the elements I tried to use the `fancyhdr` package together with `geometry` and including a `picture` environment. But I could not figure out how the position of the `picture` is being calculated. Something like this (whole code and result shown below):

```
\fancyhead[L]{
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \headertext \\
        \begin{picture}(0,0)(\geometryleft,-\geometrytop)
            \put(0, 0){\fbox{fancyhdr}}
        \end{picture}
    \end{minipage}
}
```

But when I change the page layout by using `\newgeometry` the element changes its position. The `\geometryleft` works. After reading the [`geometry` documentation](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) I modified the `\geometrytop` but I was not able to find the correct calculation. According to the docs I was expecting that the correct term is

```
\top - \headsep - \layoutvoffset.
```

But this is not correct. (For a better clearness I only wrote `\geometrytop` here.)

Also I tried to use the `everypage` package because I have to include it anyway. It seems like the `everypage` version positions the elements indipendently of the `geometry` package but still I could not figure out how to calculate the correct `0/0`-point to set it in the top left corner. The short code looks something like this (whole code and result shown below):

```
\AddEverypageHook{
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(\hoffset+1in,-\voffset-1in)
        \put(0, 0){fbox{everypage}}
    \end{picture}
}
```

Because the layout changing of the `geometry` package are completely ignored I was expecting that the `everypage` version uses the (La-?)TeX defaults. I found them to be `\hoffset + 1 in` for the left margin and `\voffset + 1 in` for the top offset. As in the `fancyhdr` version the left offset works, the right one is wrong.

Now my question is: **How do I get the correct distances from the top and left of the paper to the `picture`-environment position?** Which version I use does not matter. If you know another possibility (without including an additional pacakge if possible) I would also appreciate it.

Note that I want to avoid using `tikz`. Also I am not placing simple boxes but I am "calling" definded commands. Those commands contain the `put{}` command itself. It is very important for them that the coordinate origin will always be the same.

A working minimal example can be found below the image. The results of both versions are shown in the image below. There are boxes (in the top left corner). **Both of them should exactly be in the corner on every page**, no matter how the layout is changed.

[image]

The full code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newlength{\geometryleft}
\setlength{\geometryleft}{2cm}
\newlength{\geometryright}
\setlength{\geometryright}{2cm}
\newlength{\geometrytop}
\setlength{\geometrytop}{5.5cm}
\newlength{\geometrybottom}
\setlength{\geometrybottom}{1cm}
\newlength{\geometryheadheight}
\setlength{\geometryheadheight}{5.5cm}

\usepackage[
    showframe,
    left=\geometryleft, 
    right=\geometryright, 
    top=\geometrytop, 
    bottom=\geometrybottom, 
    headheight=\geometryheadheight
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{everypage}

\newcommand{\headertext}{Text of the first header}

\fancypagestyle{fancyhdr}{
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{%
        \hbox to\textwidth{%
            \color{black}\leaders\hrule height .4pt\hfill%
        }%
    }
    \renewcommand{\footrule}{%
        \hbox to\textwidth{%
            \color{black}\leaders\hrule height .4pt\hfill%
        }%
    }

    \fancyhead[L]{%
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \headertext \\
            \begin{picture}(0,0)(\geometryleft,-\geometrytop+3cm)
                \fbox{fancyhdr}
            \end{picture}
        \end{minipage}
    }
}

\pagestyle{fancyhdr}

\AddEverypageHook{
    \begin{picture}(0,0)(\hoffset+1in,-\voffset-1in)
    \fbox{everypage}
    \end{picture}
}

\begin{document}
    Text 
    
    \clearpage
    \renewcommand{\headertext}{
        A lot longer header text \\
        with \\
        multiple \\
        lines \\
        so \\
        it \\ 
        is \\ 
        higher
    }
    Text
    
    \clearpage
    \setlength{\geometryheadheight}{2cm}
    \newgeometry{
        headheight=\geometryheadheight,
        top=\geometrytop,
        left=\geometryleft,
        right=\geometryright
    }
    Text
    
    \clearpage
    \setlength{\geometryleft}{5cm}
    \setlength{\geometryright}{.5cm}
    \setlength{\geometrytop}{.5cm}
    \newgeometry{
        headheight=\geometryheadheight,
        top=\geometrytop,
        left=\geometryleft
        ,right=\geometryright
    }
    Text
\end{document}
```

---

## Why @David Carlisle answer is not working

The code below shows why the code of @David Carlisle is not working. My problem is, that the page dimension is changing in the document but my commands (`\fancycommand`) do not know how they are changing. The following code shows his code in my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newlength{\geometryleft}
\setlength{\geometryleft}{2cm}
\newlength{\geometryright}
\setlength{\geometryright}{2cm}
\newlength{\geometrytop}
\setlength{\geometrytop}{5.5cm}
\newlength{\geometrybottom}
\setlength{\geometrybottom}{1cm}
\newlength{\geometryheadheight}
\setlength{\geometryheadheight}{5.5cm}

\usepackage[
    showframe,
    left=\geometryleft, 
    right=\geometryright, 
    top=\geometrytop, 
    bottom=\geometrybottom, 
    headheight=\geometryheadheight
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{everypage}

\newcommand{\headertext}{Text of the first header}

\fancypagestyle{fancyhdr}{
    \fancyhead[L]{%
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
            \put(-57,117){\fancycommand}

            % this is only included to show that the fancytext is
            % still displayed and that the position changes
            \put(0,0){\fancycommand}
        \end{picture}%
        \headertext
    }
}

\newcommand{\fancycommand}{\put(10, -10){\color{red}Fancy text}}

\pagestyle{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
    Text 
    
    \clearpage
    \renewcommand{\headertext}{
        A lot longer header text \\
        with \\
        multiple \\
        lines \\
        so \\
        it \\ 
        is \\ 
        higher
    }
    Text
    
    \clearpage
    \setlength{\geometryheadheight}{2cm}
    \newgeometry{
        headheight=\geometryheadheight,
        top=\geometrytop,
        left=\geometryleft,
        right=\geometryright
    }
    Text
    
    \clearpage
    \setlength{\geometryleft}{5cm}
    \setlength{\geometryright}{.5cm}
    \setlength{\geometrytop}{.5cm}
    \newgeometry{
        headheight=\geometryheadheight,
        top=\geometrytop,
        left=\geometryleft
        ,right=\geometryright
    }
    Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the result you can see that on page one (left) the red "Fancy text" is displayed perfectly on the top left corner of the page. On the second page this is not the case anymore. This is because the layout changed. The problem is, that the position in the `fancyhdr` `put{}` is hard coded here. This has to be dependent on the page layout. Exactly this is my question: How the position (no matter if the first `put` or the origin of the `picture` environment) depends on the page margins.

The `\fancycommand` should only set its coordinate relative to the complete page. It should not be necessary to check the page dimensions. So the `\fancycommand` uses the full page as a coordinate system. I hope this helps to clarify my question.

Comment: note it is better to make the examples inline here complete rather than link to an external site, unless you can guarantee that the example will be there forever as this question and answers are archived forever.

Comment: Thank your for pointing this out. I never thought about this. I moved the code to the question and removed the link

Comment: @miile7: You can position elements absolutely using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)'s `\AtPageUpperLeft`. It's not clear to me what you want though.

Comment: @Werner thank you. I will check this out even though I want to avoid additional packages. My goal is that the *fancyhdr* or the *everypage* box in the images are at the same position on each of the pages in my example.

Comment: your heading is only misplaced because it is badly specified, fancyheader does warn you Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (56.9055pt): 
 Make it at least 94.54448pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's much easier using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)'s `\AtPageUpperLeft` to place content at the upper-left of the page:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
      \fbox{everypage}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

Since content is usually placed on the baseline, `\raisebox{-\height}{<stuff>}` ensures that the top of `<stuff>` will be at the top of the page inside `\AtPageUpperLeft`.

[image]

Comment: This works very well. I wanted to avoid adding additional packages because I have to keep the compilation time as short as possible. After a quick benchmark I found out that there is no difference. (The `eso-pic` version was even faster but the time difference is in the range of errors, so in reality there is no difference I think.)

Answer (score 3):

beware adding spaces and also `picture` mode content should always be in `\put` so

```
\fancyhead[L]{%
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
            \put(10,-200){\fbox{fancyhdr}}
        \end{picture}%
    \headertext
}
```

would put the `\fbox{fanchdr}` at 10,-200 relative to the left edge of the page header, you can adjust the coordinates to place it anywhere on the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This shows me that my question was not clear. I am looking for a way to set the coordinate origin (the `0/0`-point) to the top corner of the paper. The `\fbox{}` was only added for the demo. I am "calling" a lot of commands which use the `\put` command. This is why I did not add the `\put` command.

Comment: @miile7 so that's what this answer does, the zero sized picture is at the top left of the page and you can add as many `\put` as you need at whatever coordinates you need.

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that it is not working for me. Or I got your idea wrong. I updated my question because it is too long for a comment. I hope I understood what you wanted to tell me and my problem is more clear after reading my update.

Comment: @miile7 your setup is _very_ weird:-) the whole point of page head and foot is that they are at a fixed position, and somehow you have broken that, also why all the `\setlength` with e-tex it doesn't really matter as there are plenty of lengths but in classical latex (ie pre 2015)  you'd have been in danger of running out of length register allocation:-) I'll run your example and see if I can debug.

Comment: You are right, my setup **is weird** :) Thank you for pointing out the "filling the length register". I haven't thought about this yet. My header and footer are at a fixed position. But not when I change the position. This happens in my document because the header is changing. In addition I don't know **how** the header is changing. This makes it very complicated (for me).